# Check permission of the directory in VBA Access before creating folder

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to implement a certain feature in the Microsoft Access Database using VBA, so when a certain button is pressed, it will check first the availability of the folder in a server. If the folder doesn't exist, the corresponding folder will be created. However, the folders have permissions attached to them, which means only certain users can access it, and hence only certain users should create / access the folder. I have tried the following:

```
on error resume next
If Dir("Server/Data/Celes", vbDirectory) = "Celes" Then
Else
    MkDir ("Server/Data/Celes")
End If
```

But I'm not sure if it's the best way to handle this problem. I use the "On Error Resume Next", so that if the error occurs due to the lack of permission to the folder (that already exists), it will ignore it. What are some better ways to handle this? Thank you.

I also have checked the following links:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a79054cb-52cf-48fd-955b-aa38fd18dc1f/vba-verify-if-user-has-permission-to-directory-before-saveas-attempt?forum=exceldev
- [Check Folder Permissions Before Save VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287485/check-folder-permissions-before-save-vba)

but both of them concerns with saving the file, not creating folder.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27293323/9199828) shows the code to check the permisssion of the folder. Just adapt it to your needs. You don't want to save the workbook, so in your case, probably you need something like `If (process to check permissions) then (process to create the folder)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days without success, finally I found the solution:

```
Private function canAccess(path as string) as boolean
    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Dim result As Integer
    Dim command As String
    command = "icacls " & """" & pfad & """"
    result = oShell.Run(command, 0, True)
    'Check privilege; file can be accessed if error code is 0.
    'Else, errors are encountered, and error code > 0.

    If result <> 5 and result <> 6 Then
        KannAufDateiZugreifen = True
    Else
        KannAufDateiZugreifen = False
    End If
end function

private sub button_click()
    if canAccess ("Server/Data/Celes") then
        If Dir("Server/Data/Celes", vbDirectory) = "Celes" Then
        Else
            MkDir ("Server/Data/Celes")
        end if
    End If
end sub
```

The function "canAccess" will simulate the running of the Windows shell, and execute "icacls" to see if the file can be accessed or not. If the function returns true, it means the "icacls" command is successful, which means the folder can be accessed. Otherwise, the file / folder can not be accessed.

I'm pretty sure this can be improved, but for now, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below function that recursively creates the full path (if required) and returns a value indicating success or failure. It works also with UNCs.

```
Private Function CreateFolder(ByVal sPath As String) As Boolean
'by Patrick Honorez - www.idevlop.com
'checks for existence of a folder and create it at once, if required
'returns False if folder does not exist and could NOT be created, True otherwise
'sample usage: If CreateFolder("C:\toto\test\test") Then debug.print "OK"
'updated 20130422 to handle UNC paths correctly ("\\MyServer\MyShare\MyFolder")

    Dim fs As Object
    Dim FolderArray
    Dim Folder As String, i As Integer, sShare As String

    If Right(sPath, 1) = "\" Then sPath = Left(sPath, Len(sPath) - 1)
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'UNC path ? change 3 "\" into 3 "@"
    If sPath Like "\\*\*" Then
        sPath = Replace(sPath, "\", "@", 1, 3)
    End If
    'now split
    FolderArray = Split(sPath, "\")
    'then set back the @ into \ in item 0 of array
    FolderArray(0) = Replace(FolderArray(0), "@", "\", 1, 3)
    On Error GoTo hell
    'start from root to end, creating what needs to be
    For i = 0 To UBound(FolderArray) Step 1
        Folder = Folder & FolderArray(i) & "\"
        If Not fs.FolderExists(Folder) Then
            fs.CreateFolder (Folder)
        End If
    Next
    CreateFolder = True
hell:
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

'Must set a Reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject

 Dim fil As File
 Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

 If fso.FileExists("\\serverName\folderName\fileName.txt") Then
   'code execution here
 Else
   MsgBox "File and/or Path cannot be found", vbCritical, "File Not Found"
 End If
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it,         and format it properly