# I am trying to save the current workbook with the name of an cell value, the file should be saved to a specific directory

Tags: excel, vba

This code attempts to save the file the C:\ directory. The file name is a cell reference (PS: The cell is a formula not a value i don't know if this has any effect on my error.)

The error I am getting:

> "Run-time error '1004': Microsoft Excel cannot access the File 'C:\"String of random Numbers"'.

```
Sub Save_File()
    Dim FileNameStr As String
    Dim Path As String
    FileNameStr = Worksheets("Data").Range("B19")
    Path = "C:\" & FileNameStr & ".xlsm"
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of FileNameStr?

Comment: This Formula =B17&"_kv_"&B16&"_"&B15 which results in k_119_kv_23012020_mh

Comment: I recommend changing the variable name to something that is not a VBA command, such as `MyFilePath`.

Comment: For sure a good idea but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You probably do not have the right to save the file to C:\. Just try to copy a file there and I guess you won't be able to.

Comment: Yeah you were right i didn't have permission to save the file in C:\! Thanks very much.

Comment: With this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858202/6600940) you can check beforehand if you have write access.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have the right to save the file to C:. Just try to copy a file there and I guess you won't be able to. – Storax

Comment: This is not an answer. Please delete!